# Sed - Insert line with text after match pattern between two strings

Tags: bash, sed

I want to insert text below line with certain string only in block between two patterns.
Example input file:

```
text text
text text
...
[textabc pattern 1]
text text
text text
xyz = 123 #below this string I want to insert new text
text text
[textdef pattern 2]
text text
text text
```

I want to insert "NEW STRING" below line "xyz = 123" but only if string is between "[textabc pattern 1]" and "[textdef pattern 2]".
Output file:

```
text text
text text
...
[textabc pattern 1]
text text
text text
xyz = 123
NEW STRING
text text
[textdef pattern 2]
text text
text text
```

I have tried something like this:

```
sed -i '/^\[textabc pattern 1\]$/,/^\[textdef pattern 2\]/ ^xyz .*/a NEW STRING/' /folder/file.txt
```

How do I do this using sed?

Comment: Seems like you would need to write a script and iterate through the file twice. Have a boolean flag to indicate whether you find the "opening" tag, an int to indicate the line number for the desired text, and then if you find a "closing" tag before another opening tag, you'll store the line number. Pass through the file a second time and add the new text on the following line number. If there are more than one, you'll have to increment your stored line numbers. I'd personally use Python. Let me know if you need some help.

Comment: Please provide more clear samples, so that we could get more clear picture of your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data set:

```
$ cat test.txt
text text
text text
[textabc pattern 1]
text text
text text
xyz = 123
text text
[textdef pattern 2]
text text
text text
```

A couple small changes to OPs current `sed` command:

```
# current

sed     '/^\[textabc pattern 1\]$/,/^\[textdef pattern 2\]/ ^xyz .*/a NEW STRING/' test.txt

# new/proposed (2 lines); the 'a'ppend option requires a new line before the end '}'

sed  -e '/^\[textabc pattern 1\]$/,/^\[textdef pattern 2\]/{/^xyz .*/aNEW STRING
}' test.txt

# new/proposed (1 line); break into 2 segments via a 2nd '-e' flag to eliminate need for embedded newline character

sed  -e '/^\[textabc pattern 1\]$/,/^\[textdef pattern 2\]/{/^xyz .*/a'"NEW STRING" -e '}' test.txt
```

Both of the above new/proposed `sed` commands generate the following:

```
text text
text text
[textabc pattern 1]
text text
text text
xyz = 123
NEW STRING
text text
[textdef pattern 2]
text text
text text
```

**NOTE**: Once OP is satisfied with the results the `-i` flag can be reintroduced to allow `sed` to make in-place changes to data file.

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work - something is wrong. Or I'm doing something wrong. The second suggestion - great. Thanks.

Comment: re: first suggestion: without seeing the actual code you're trying to run, I'd guess you've tried to run the command as a single-line ... it **has** to be done across 2 lines (ie, there has to be a newline character after `NEW STRING`)

Comment: @markp-fuso I have a similar problem but I need to just look into one block so essentially I need to remove the part where it includes `[textdef pattern 2]`. Can you please help me with this modification in your one-liner solution?

Comment: @shashwat I suggest you ask a new question, making sure to provide the normal stuff ... sample input, code youv'e tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; regards

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[textabc pattern 1\]/{               # match the first pattern
     :a                                     # loop name
     N                                      # append next line
     /\[textdef pattern 2\]/!ba             # match the second pattern or repeat
     s/^xyz = 123.*$/&\nNEW STRING/m}' file # match third pattern and append
```